# using Backbone JS boilerplate & code navigation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, boilerplate

a newbe question:
I've downloaded the backbone boilerplate from https://github.com/david0178418/BackboneJS-AMD-Boilerplate it uses require.js and I wonder about the code navigation during development.

Here is my question:
let's say I have 2 views one extend the other like so:

View 1:

```
define([
    'underscoreLoader',
    'backboneLoader',
    'text!templates/main.html'
],
    function (_, Backbone, MainTemplate) {
        "use strict";

        return Backbone.View.extend({
            template:_.template(MainTemplate),

            initialize:function () {
                this.render();
            },

            log:function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            },

            render:function () {
                this.$el.append(this.template({}));
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

View 2:

```
define([
    'underscoreLoader',
    'backboneLoader',
    'text!templates/other.html',
    'views/main-view'
],
    function (_, Backbone, MainTemplate,MainView) {
        "use strict";

        // how would you navigate to MainView (main-view.js) 

        return MainView.extend({
            template:_.template(MainTemplate),

            initialize:function () {
                this.render();
            },

            render:function () {
                this.log("my message");
                this.$el.append(this.template({}));
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now when I develop (I use IntelliJ) I would like to middle click **MainView** on the extended view and navigate to the code without having to browse the project tree.

Is that possible using this boilerplate? is there a better approach or a better boilerplate?

Comment: _Is that possible using this boilerplate?_</br>
I haven't used IntelliJ but this sounds highly unlikely as RequireJS decouples your application and the "MainView" variable could be anything from a static analysis point of view. And only at runtime is this pointing to the actual MainView. </br>
_is there a better approach or a better boilerplate?_</br>
Don't use RequireJS if you want IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Since code navigation is not limited to a certain IDE and is a require feature during development phase, I would really like to find a solution, meaning :keeping the files separated and still have a reference to the code.

Comment: Javascript, at least for me, is a complete paradigm shift when it comes to development tools. I use just Notepad++. There is no autocomplete, no automatic error highlighting, no refactoring helpers and other such goodies I was used to when working with strongly typed languages such as C#. The sooner you realize this the better in my opinion :).

Comment: Not exactly true, there are many good JS IDEs such as NetBeans ,IntelliJ. they do have automatic error highlighting, refactoring and much more. but this is not my question. I believe a different approach can be used in order to enjoy both worlds.

Comment: Please rewrite your question. The code is irrelevant, backbone is irrelevant. All you need is: How can I use IntelliJ's X stuff with require.js

Comment: Thanks, actually what I really want is a good structure for backbone js, that will allow code navigation. require.js was just what came with that specific boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work fine for me:
the Backbone Objects are wrapped with my custom objects, which allows me to navigate code, extend objects and keep multiple files easily.

Here is how:

Object 1

```
function ItemModel() {
    ItemModel.model = (
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize:function () {

            },
            defaults:{
                name:"item name"
            },
            log:function(){
                console.log("inherited method");
            }
        })
        );
    return new ItemModel.model();
}
```

Object 2

```
function ItemModel2() {
    ItemModel2.model = (
        ItemModel.model.extend({
            initialize:function () {

            },
            defaults:{
                name:"item name2"
            }
        })
        );
    return new ItemModel2.model();
}
```

and in my app:

```
var App = {
    item:new ItemModel(),
    item2:new ItemModel2()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would really like Netbeans's navigator to show me all the methods:

```
var New_Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : null, ...
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Google came up with something for @lends, but I can't even get Backbone.js to get loaded to the code hint cache.

I ended up installing WebStorm (I saw the IDE in all the egghead.io tutorials) to get the navigator to list all methods and properties.

FYI, Aptana Studio and Zend Studio showed nothing like Netbeans. And Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers only partially (impractical in real life) works; it flattens the entire hierarchy.